# Напишите решение задачи ("Драконий покер")

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм

Драконий покер - сложная игра и в нем есть специальный раунд, где требуется сбросить ровно n
карт, для того что бы набрать нужное количество баллов. Карты требуется сбрасывать как можно
быстрее. У игрока не может быть больше чем m карт. Изначально карт у игрока нет.
Игрок может взять ровно m карт за a секунд, или добрать всего одну карту за b секунд. Сброс
одной карты занимает ровно одну секунду. Помогите посчитать, за какое минимальное время игрок
сможет сбросить ровно n карт. Нельзя добрать карту, если у игрока уже m карт.
Формат входных данных
В строке находятся четыре целых числа n, m, a и b (1 <= n, m, a, b <= 10^4) — число карт, которое
сбросить, максимальное количество карт, которое может быть у игрока, время за которое можно
взять из колоды ровно m карт, и время за которое можно взять всего одну карту из колоды.
Формат выходных данных
Выведите одно число — минимальное время, которое понадобится игроку, что бы сбросить ровно
n карт.
Пример

```
стандартный ввод
3 2 1 1

стандартный вывод
5
```

Замечание
В тесте из условия требуется один раз полностью взять m карт, два раза сбросить по одной
карте, потом добрать одну карту из колоды и сбросить ее.

Есть такой пример моего кода, но больше примера он не проходит, почему ?

```
n,m,a,b = map(int, input ().split())
time = 0
cart = 0

while n > 0:
    if cart + m > m:
        n-=1
        cart -= 1
        time += 1
    else:
        if n - 1 == 0 and b <= a:
            cart += 1
            time += b
        else:
            cart += m
            time += a

print(time)
```

Comment: Верно. Помощи в программировании. Только тут нечему помогать, потому что никакого программирования тут не наблюдается.

Comment: у меня есть такой код: n,m,a,b = map(int, input ().split())
time = 0
cart = 0

while n > 0:
    if cart + m > m:
        n-=1
        cart -= 1
        time += 1
    else:
        if n - 1 == 0 and b <= a:
            cart += 1
            time += b
        else:
            cart += m
            time += a

print(time)

Но он больше одного теста не проходит, почему ?

Comment: сначала сюда - [ask], потом редактировать вопрос (кнопка Править под текстом вопроса).

Comment: Спасибо, за мой недочёт, исправил

Comment: ``if cart + m > m:`` - тут вероятно ошибка

Comment: У меня отрабатывает как с стандартным вводом, так и рандомным. Какую у вас ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: У меня алгоритм не правильный, мой код работает только на тестовый пример 3 2 1 1, а на втором ошибка в решении, в чем ошибка ?

Comment: @Роман боюсь вопрос застрянет, т.к. по сути надо перерешить задачу за вас, в неё надо вникать, а там простыня. Попробуйте переформатировать задачу, расписать списком что такое `n`, `m`, `a` и `b`, добавить форматирование, иначе лично я глаза ломаю в едином абзаце.

Comment: можно ссылку на проверяющую систему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуем по-простому:

```
n + min( (n//m)*a+(n%m)*b, ((n+m-1)//m)*a,   n*b)
```

Три случая - пачки по m + остаток по одной, все карты набраны в пачках с возможным перебором в последний раз (когда b велико), все карты берутся по одной (когда a велико)